# Google nearBy BLE background subscription only for screen on events

Tags: android, google-nearby

As per the current Google nearBy documentation, for background BLE subscription
"low-power scans are triggered only at screen-on events, even when your app is not currently active."
https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages#subscribe_in_the_background

The application i was designing needed to notify the user even when the screen is Off.
Is there anyway to get the callback irrespective of this screen-on trigger using the NearBy API approach.

Comment: Why not use your app to trigger the notification?

Comment: You can trigger a notification once you get the callback from NearBy API, which is limited to only screen-on events when app is in the background.

Comment: Hey @AndroidUser, was wondering if you found a solution for your requirement of scanning for BLE devices in the background and waking up the application. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, we don't support this for power reasons. You can implement this using the lower level BluetoothLeScanner API and a background service, but you may be subject to other restrictions on newer versions of Android.

Comment: Is that any plans of supporting BLE scanning callback at the android framework level similar to iOS iBeacon ranging ?